# Implement a function inv(n) that returns the number of invertible elements in Zn in python

Tags: python, function

I have been working on this homework problem for over an hour and I don't even know where to begin. I would like to understand how to get the answer not just get an answer. I am working in python. The question is:

Implement a function `inv(n)` that returns the number of invertible elements in Zn. For example, `inv(5)`
should output `4` and `inv(100)` should output `40`.

Thanks

Comment: I woul start with `def inv(n):` ... no one knows what you are talking about ... we arent taking that class... how would you do it with a pencil and paper?

Comment: @Joran Beasley: see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: If you "don't even know know where to begin" I doubt your problem at this point is with `python` or `function` (the tags you used), and probably more with the math/algorithm/....

Comment: You've edited this question to make it incomprehensible. It previously asked for the number of invertible elements and gave some examples, but now it asks for the number of "multiplicative elements" which doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
def inv(n):
    result = 0
    for x in range(1, n):
        for y in range(1, n):
            if x * y % n == 1:
                result += 1
    return result

print inv(5)
print inv(100)
```

Results:

```
4
40
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `inv` is more commonly known as the [Euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

One way to compute it is to use the fact that it's equal to n times the product of (1 - 1/p) for each prime p that divides n.

Using a Sieve of Erastothenes, you can compute this relatively efficiently, with the code running in time O(sqrt(n) * log log n).

```
import math

def totient(n):
    sn = int(math.sqrt(n)) + 2
    a = [True] * sn
    result = n
    for i in xrange(2, sn):
        if not a[i]:
            continue
        for j in xrange(i * 2, sn, i):
            a[j] = False
        if n % i == 0:
            result = result - result // i
    if result == n:
        # n is prime.
        result -= 1
    return result

for i in xrange(1, 101):
    print i, totient(i)
```